# Unable to reference standard add attachment URL

Tags: apex

I'm trying to use apex to redirect to the standard add attachment URL. If I click on the Add Attachment button in the related list of an object detail page, I get the following URL:

`https://mycustomdomain.cs20.my.salesforce.com/p/attach/NoteAttach?pid=a07m0000008dchk&parentname=TestRecord&retURL=%2Fa07m0000008dchk`

In my code, I'm trying to build the URL and redirect to it instead of having to build out a custom VF page with the add attachment functionality.

Here is some code I was trying:

```
PageReference ref = new PageReference('');
Map<String, String> params = ref.getParameters();
params.put('pid', record.Id);
params.put('retURL', record.Id);
return 'true1;' + '/p/attach/NoteAttach'+ref.getURL();
```

when I run the code, the URL I get is:
`https://mycustomdomain.cs20.my.salesforce.com/p/attach/NoteAttach?pid=a07m0000008dciTAAQ&amp`

The page doesn't display correctly...it only shows a portion of the top of the page, but if I refresh, then the whole add attachment page displays. 
[image]

Also, the return URL parameter is missing. How can I get the page to load correctly where it displays properly when it first loads and how can I get the retURL URL parameter to be included in the URL?

Comment: retURL should be `'/'+record.Id`

Comment: I made the adjustment for the retURL to be `'/'+record.Id` but I still get the same result.

Comment: i was wrong; my bad ...thinking

Comment: what is `true1;` ? are you doing a `ref.setRedirect(true)` somewhere?

Comment: the class is using a `@remoteAction` method that returns a string to a VF page using AngularJS that splits the string using the `;` as the delimiter and then using `window.location.href` to redirect to the parsed URL portion of the string. So, no, I'm not using the `pageReference setRedirect(true)` method.

Comment: this is outside my area of expertise; hopefully someone else can jump in